# Wait until text is not present in textbox selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Below is the scenario I am trying to automate:

```
1) Some text is already present in Textbox.
2) Click on Radio button.
3) Processing popup is displayed for few seconds. After popup disappears the textbox 
   becomes blank
4) After textbox is blank then I have to enter different value in text box.
```

Please help me, how to wait till textbox value is blank.

I am automating with IE driver.

Thanks In advance

Comment: Share your code please.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Below code worked for me.

```
    WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_cphClaimFlow_tabcontainerClaimFlow_tabFulfillment_Shipping_ctl33_txtStreeAddress1"));
     String myInitialText=element.getAttribute("value");
     //click on radio btn
     driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_cphClaimFlow_tabcontainerClaimFlow_tabFulfillment_Shipping_ctl33_radNewAddress")).click();
     logger.info("New Address radio button clicked");
     System.out.println("1 "+myInitialText);
    while(!myInitialText.equals("")){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            logger.info("Thread is sleeping");
            //System.out.println("2 "+myInitialText);
            myInitialText=driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_cphClaimFlow_tabcontainerClaimFlow_tabFulfillment_Shipping_ctl33_txtStreeAddress1")).getAttribute("value");
            //System.out.println("3 "+myInitialText);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_cphClaimFlow_tabcontainerClaimFlow_tabFulfillment_Shipping_ctl33_txtStreeAddress1")).sendKeys(td.getAddressLine1().get(0));
     logger.info("Address Line1 entered");
```

Comment: That is a great example of how NOT to do it. Your ID is duplicated through the code, you print to stdout, you use `Thread.sleep`, you swallow exceptions, and you didn't clean up the commented out lines from the code. I'd probably not fire you just yet, but you're getting close.

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

`int timeout = 10; // depends on your needs
WebDriverWait myWait= new WebDriverWait(driver,timeout);
myWait.until(ExpectedCondition.textToBePresentInElementValue(By locator, String text))`
-- with empty string passed as text argument

Comment: I tried the scenario but it is appending new text to old text in textbox while processing popup is displayed. And when processing popup disappears, then the textbox becomes blank.

Comment: The adding is either a "feature" of the app or of your test. Regardless, you want to wait for the blank field, so intermediate state should not be a problem.  If the value returned is not "" but null, create custom expected condition by copying ExpectedCondition.textToBePresentInElementValue() and changing the logic so its  apply method returns true on empty string or null.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :-

```
public void waitUntilTextNotToBeInWebElement(WebElement element, String textValue) {
    int timer = 0;
    final int pollInterval = 500;
    while (timer < MAX_TIME*1000) {
        if (element.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(textValue)) {
           sleep(500);
           timer += pollInterval;
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
    throw new TimeoutException("Maximum time exceeded.");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi there is two possible way through which you can do this

1.Use Expected condition

```
// after you have clicked on radio button and it does some processing
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementWithText(locator, "your text"));
    // now perform your operation
```

2. use if else

   ```
   // get the text of input box like below 
   String myInitialText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("")).getAttribute("value");
   // click on radio button 
   // now apply the logic
           if(myInitialText == null){
               System.out.println("Input box is blank");
              // perform next operation
       }else{
           Thread.sleep(5000);
       }
   // now fill the input box
   ```

Comment: Read the question, it is exactly opposite. The user wants to enter text only after the Text box is blank.

Comment: yes u r right ,but i do not see any issue in my answer it tells to perform next operation only after input box is blank

Comment: if(text==null){SOP} , this is only printing the message "Input box is blank", and not doing any other operation.
If you want any operation to be performed, you have to include it inside **if** block.

Comment: yes if its printing "Input box is blank" that means your earlier text is gone so you can proceed with your next operation whats wrong in that and before down voting please understand then down vote

Comment: Thanks for the edit, you have edited and put this line afterwards **// perform next operation**, now this makes it correct. Hope you get the downvote reason!

Comment: Thanks for understanding,edited to make you and others understand how we can perform next operation once we are inside the if loop ,anyways thanks

Comment: @rajNishKuMar I have tried the seocond approach. Below is my code.

Comment: String myInitialText=driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_cphClaimFlow_tabcontainerClaimFlow_tabFulfillment_Shipping_ctl33_txtStreeAddress1")).getAttribute("value");
   //click on radiobtn
 driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_cphClaimFlow_tabcontainerClaimFlow_tabFulfillment_Shipping_ctl33_radNewAddress")).click();
   logger.info("New Address radio button clicked");

   if(myInitialText == null){
             System.out.println("Input box is blank");
       element.sendKeys(td.getAddressLine1().get(0));

     }
   else{
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    logger.info("Thread is sleeping");
     }'

Comment: else condition is executing but I need to enter value in textbox. What should I do. Should I again check if textbox is blank? But I don't think it will be good practise. Please suggest. @rajNishKuMar

Comment: Also First approach will not work as invisibilityOfElementWithText is used for checking that an element with text is either invisible or not present on the DOM. The Textbox will be present.